# Add extra text while databinding

Tags: c#, string, data-binding

I'm trying to add some extra text to the following code but it doesn't seem to work whatever I do. The information I want to show in a label comes from a DataBinding. But I can't manipulate it like a usual string

```
lblPower.DataBindings.Add("Text", BindingSourceMachineProfiles, nameof(MachineProfile.NominalPower));
```

At the moment the label only displays a number but I would like to add before the description and at the back the units.

So I would like to have e.g. `"Speed" + code from above + "km/h"`

How could I do this using the current code?

Comment: What UI are you using? Winforms, WPF, UWP, WebForms, something else?

Comment: See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/string-formatting

Comment: See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.bindingbase.stringformat?view=windowsdesktop-6.0

Comment: @gunr2171 I'm using Windows Forms App

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution by using `Binding.Format` Below I have made an example of how I use it in my app.

```
var SpeedBinding = new Binding("Text", BindingSource);
SpeedBinding.Format += delegate (object sentFrom, ConvertEventArgs convertEventArgs)
{
convertEventArgs.Value = "Speed: " + convertEventArgs.Value + " km/h";
};

lblPower.DataBindings.Add(SpeedBinding);
```

This gives me nice results